# Building a suitable mixed effects logistic regression model taking into account gender (R)

Tags: r, regression, logistic, mixed-model, generalized-linear-model

I'm new to regression analysis but I'm currently building a mixed effects logistic regression model having `Pitch` as the dependent variable and `DurationZ`, `PitchMax`, `IntenMax`, `Gender` as fixed effects and `Subject` (person) as a random effect.

`Pitch` is a binary `yes`/`no` and other variables are either `numeric` or `factors`.

I have a few versions of the model and I don't know which one of them will be the most accurate one. And how should I treat `Gender` if I know that it has an effect on other independent parameters (`PitchMax*Gender` or `(1+PitchMax|Gender)`?:

`library(lme4)`

```
testModel1 <- glmer(Pitch~DurationZ+PitchMax+IntenMax+Gender+
                   (1+DurationZ|Subject)+(1+PitchMax|Subject)+
                   (1+IntenMax|Subject),
                   data = TotalOutlScaled5, family = binomial, 
                   control = glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa"))
```

Or

```
testModel2 <- glmer(Pitch~DurationZ+PitchMax+IntenMax+Gender+ 
                    PitchMax*Gender + IntenMax*Gender + DurationZ*Gender+
                   (1+DurationZ|Subject)+(1+PitchMax|Subject)+
                   (1+IntenMax|Subject),
                   data = TotalOutlScaled5, family = binomial, control = 
                   glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa"))
```

Or

```
testModel3 <- glmer(Pitch~DurationZ+PitchMax+IntenMax+
                    (1+DurationZ|Subject)+(1+PitchMax|Subject)+ 
                    (1+IntenMax|Subject)+ 
                    (1+DurationZ|Gender)+ (1+PitchMax|Gender)+ 
                    (1+IntenMax|Gender),
                    data = TotalOutlScaled5, family = binomial, 
                    control = glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa"))
```

Or

```
 testModel4 <- glmer(Pitch~DurationZ+PitchMax+IntenMax+
                        (1|Gender)+(1|Subject),
                        data = TotalOutlScaled5, family = binomial, 
                        control = glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa"))




> str(TotalOutlScaled5)
'data.frame':   66917 obs. of 6 variables:
 $ Pitch     : Factor w/ 2 levels "no","yes": 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 2 ...
 $ DurationZ : num  0.516 0.356 0.351 0.268 0.26 ...
 $ PitchMax  : num  0.2638 0.3348 0.2603 0.1732 0.0703 ...
 $ IntenMax  : num  0.74 0.734 0.718 0.626 0.647 ...
 $ Gender    : Factor w/ 2 levels "F","M": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ Subject   : Factor w/ 8 levels "A","B","C","D",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

Comment: @MartijnWeterings The idea is to predict Pitch with the help of different parameters, i.e. DurationZ, PitchMax, IntenMax (syllable duration, maximum pitch, maximum intensity) (I have more parameters in fact than that. I just don't use them here because of overwhelming). I'm going to experiment with the models using different parameters to see which one is a better fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Gender as random effect**

Your first and second model seem most plausible. The third and fourth model with random effects for gender are a bit strange. This would imply as if you had been picking gender randomly (creating the random error) out of a pool/population with many genders.

**Model 1 vs 2**

Here you did not change the mixed effects but only the fixed effects <sup>(where the extra cross term with gender could be written by a:b, and a*b, equaling a + b + a:b, is all fixed + cross terms)</sup>.

So the difference between these two models is an issue of model selection.

**Correlation**

One more point that you would have to find out is whether the `glmer` function allows all slopes to correlate with the intercept. The

```
(1+DurationZ|Subject) + (1+PitchMax|Subject) + (1+IntenMax|Subject)
```

differs from

```
(1|Subject) + (DurationZ - 1|Subject) + (PitchMax - 1|Subject) + (IntenMax - 1|Subject)
```

and

```
(1+DurationZ+PitchMax+IntenMax|Subject)
```

In how the random errors in the slope and intercept correlate and if the random errors in the slopes are considered to correlate with each other. Possibly the first one (slopes correlating with the intercept but not, directly, with each other) might not be possible in every software implication.